# Update editor view in Shopware admin CMS component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, shopware, shopware6

When creating a new CMS element to be used in Shopware's WYSIWYG editor we have three components: one named `component`, another `configComponent` and a third named `previewComponent`.

The `configComponent` is apparently used to select the configuration for an element, while the `component` component is used to update the view in the editor. E.g. Display what was selected in the config part. My problem is that it will only update the view in the editor after the user has clicked the save button, which creates a bad user experience – it should update live.

**I think I need to somehow `$emit` an update event** when an entity ID has been selected from the `configComponent`, and then pass on the ID of the selected entity to the `component` component.

So, I have the following in the `component` twig:

```js
  <config-component @entity-picked="entityPickedHandler" />
```

This should, according to how I interpret the documentation, call the "entityPickedHandler" method in `component` when the `entity-picked` event is emitted from `configComponent`.

E.g. This is the event handler method in `component`:

```js
methods: {
  entityPickedHandler(data) {
    console.log('Event triggered:', data);
  }
}
```

And from `configComponent` I then emit the event:

```js
computed: {
  myEntity: {
    get() {
      return this.element.config.entity.value;
    },

    set(value) {
      // this.$set(this.element.data, 'entityId', value);
      this.element.config.entity.value = value;
      console.log('Trying to emit entity-picked event');
      this.$emit('entity-picked', value);
    }
  }
}
```

This is evidently not working, as the `console.log()` in `entityPickedHandler` handler is never outputted. The event should be emitting however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getter/Setter can be a bit iffy with the scope. Generally the approach looks to be correct. Maybe try storing the entity in a data property and having a watcher on it.

```js
data() {
    return {
        entity: this.element.config.entity.value,
    };
},

watch: {
    entity(value) {
        this.$emit('entity-picked', value);
    },
},

methods: {
    entityChanged(value) {
        this.element.config.entity.value = value;
        this.entity = value;
    },
},
```

**Update**
Or as a watcher from within the `component` component:

```js
watch: {
    'element.data.entityId': {
        handler() {
            this.entityId = this.element.data.entityId;
        },
        deep: true,
    }
}
```

The data can then be updated from `configComponent` with the following:

```js
computed: {
    myentity: {
        get() {
            return this.element.config.myEntity.value;
        },

        set(value) {
            this.element.config.myentity.value = value;
            this.$set(this.element.data, 'entityId', value);
            this.$emit('element-update', this.element);
        }
    }
},
```

The `myentity`method is then used in the `v-model` of the `sw-entity-single-select` in `configComponent`'s twig:

```html
{% block sw_cms_element_team_box_config %}
    <sw-entity-single-select label="testing my entity" entity="myexample_entity" v-model="myentity" />
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just found a solution myself based on what Shopware is doing in their own code; It appears we can store the data in `this.element.data.entityId` rather than `this.element.config.entityId` – and then we don't have to use a custom `$emit` at all, we only need to do a `this.$emit('element-update', this.element);` from the `configComponent` and create a watcher for `element.data.entityId`?

Comment: Yes you could do that. I added an example for nested watchers as well if you want to try that approach.